# Free ARM IDE | Compiler

Tags: ide, arm, assembly

I am looking for ARM IDE, so I could run code like this:

```
    LDR     R0, a
    a    DEFW    0
```

And it would give me results or show how is everything processed. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear if you're looking for a compiler, debugger, simulator, IDE, or all of the above. (Also please remove "best" from your title, that's completely subjective.)

Comment: @Mat, I need all of the above I guess.

Comment: And what have you found so far? Why don't they fit your needs?

Comment: @Mat: I found great one: http://brej.org/kmd/ , but I am not able to download it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with ARM assembly using free tools there is only one true solution:

- vim (or other suitable editor that matches your needs)
- gcc
- gdb + Qemu (or better gdb + ICE + board)

Or (this will cost you a fortune):

- ARM Developer Suite
- JTAG

Comment: Maybe it's possible to have everything in one program?

Comment: even times when you think you are running one gui program there are usually command line tools being called in the background.  a number of editors will do that for you.   Add to the list above jtag and openocd being affordable.  The Signalyzer LITE and jlink edu (microcontrollershop.com) work just fine, or amontek jtag-tiny, etc.  you can single step and look at the registers, etc.  you dont even need gcc for assembler just get binutils, trivial to build a cross assembler and linker.